# Using Webpack to bundle Nodejs code with node_modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

I found many tutorials on how to get things running without `node_modules`, but I want to run Webpack and end up with one JavaScript file, that contains all of my dependencies.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us anything you have done and we can get start from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Webpack configuration file in order to create one bundle file

```
output: {
    library: 'someLibName',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    auxiliaryComment: 'Test Comment'
  }
```

above will crate a bunndle in the path you have defined.